# generate .exe file from .py

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I tried to create .exe file from my python code, and it's fine on my computer but .exe file does not work on another computer. The command is:
`pyinstaller  --onefile <filename>.py`
And part of my code is:

```
hex_user = []
int_user = []
for i in range(size_username):
    hex_user.append(hex(ord(username[i])))
    int_user.append(int(format(ord(username[i]), "x"), 16))

while index <= 4:
    if counter+1 >= len(ebx):
        data = "0" + ebx[counter]
    else:
        data = ebx[counter+1]+ebx[counter]
    if int(data, 16) > 9:
        data = format(int("37", 16)+int(data, 16), 'x')
    else:
        data = format(orWith30(data), 'x')
    out += data
    serial += bytes.fromhex(data).decode("ASCII")
    index += 1
    counter += 2

print(serial)

input()
input()
```

I read character and change to hex then do some transition on them and finally, I convert them to ASCII code and don't import any library, but the error is :

> **'no module named encodings'**

Comment: Is `no module named encodings` the error other people get?

Comment: Kindly check your code, the code isn't correct.
You have not defined the variable `size_username` and still you have used it in the for loop.

Comment: Is that your complete code ? Although it looks strange to me, but try to add `encodings` as hidden import explicitly: `pyinstaller  --onefile <filename>.py --hidden-import=encodings`

Comment: yes, when someone executes the file will get that error. - @Torxed

Comment: I checked that and it didn't work. @MauriceMeyer

Comment: Please update your code snippet, it is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Import the encodings module using pip on the target computer.

Comment: Yes, that could be it.